# Startup code not running?

Tags: c#

In my application, I have it call a startup method in my MainForm class called `OnStart`, which is defined as such:

```
public void OnStart()
{
    //code
}
```

When I call it from the `Main` method, it doesn't run. What am I doing wrong?
(Oh, and the same thing as with the `OnStop` method.)

Here is my Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
            Application.Run(mainForm);  

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler (mainForm.OnStop);

            mainForm.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application.Run` will hang until your form closes so you'll need to call `OnStart` before it and `OnStop` after.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logger
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
            mainForm.OnStart();
            Application.Run(mainForm);  
            mainForm.OnStop()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I didn't know that the code "pauses" so to say, after `Application.Run` until the application is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to run the OnStart() method from within the constructor of your form. Your current code isn't called until your form closes. Same with the event handler for form.Close();

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you call those methods from the MainForm_Load event (or the constructor).  Nothing will happen after the Application.Run() method until you close the Form.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add cals *after* `Application.Run(mainForm);` , it will not work as you expected.
Add the code you want to run on `Form`'s `OnLoad` override, for example.